# What's the best way to assign variables for use in multiple form modules?

Tags: forms

We have multiple custom form modules in our Drupal 8 site, and there are variables that are common across them -- like arrays for year, semester and campus, as well as lists of courses (so it's quite a few values, and they have to be updated from time to time). What's the best (most correct) way to define these common variables in a single place so they can be accessed by any module that needs them?

Comment: The best way will change quite a bit depending on how the values need to be modified, and how you need to access them, etc. When you multiple modules share some code you may want to create an additional module, a module that will be a dependency of the other modules, with the shared code. Alternatively, it may make more sense for one of your form modules to be the dependency for the others and hold the shared stuff. That will be a decision you'll have to make.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what is the "best", but you can write a class, add the variables as constants, and then import the class wherever you need it.

For example, in `MYMODULE/src/MyVariables.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\MYMODULE\SharedStuff;
    
/**
 * Defines variables that need to be shared throughout the site.
 */
class MyVariables {

  // Seconds in an hour.
  const HOUR = 60 * 60;
  // Seconds in a day.
  const DAY = 24 * self::HOUR;
  // Seconds in a week.
  const WEEK = 7 * self::DAY;
}
```

And then in the PHP files where you need the variables:

`use Drupal\MYMODULE\SharedStuff\MyVariables;`

And then for the variable: `MyVariables::HOUR`